# How do I correctly connect AND query MySQL using MySQLi?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I started to convert my site which uses Mysql to use Mysqli but having a few problems.
Could someone help me on how I can correctly connect and query Mysql using Mysqli.

1) Below are the <strike>.Error</strike> Warning Messages on my site:

a) Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user "localhost" (using password: No) in /myside/xxxx/xxxxx/functions.php on line 3556

b) Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /myside/xxxx/xxxxx/functions.php on line 3556

c) Warning: mysql_results() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /myside/xxxx/xxxxx/functions.php on line 3558

2) MYSQL Query function code that I use for from line 3544 till 3558:

```
// Get Custom Post Type post count
function get_stats($uid,$type,$sub_type = "all") {
if ($type == "reviews") {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_comments WHERE user_id =    $uid AND comment_approved = 1");
} elseif ($type == "listings") {
    if ($sub_type == "all") {
        $post_types =   get_post_types_custom(unserialize(EXCLUDED_CUSTOM_POST_TYPES));
    } else {
        $post_types = "'".$sub_type."'";
    }
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_posts WHERE post_author = $uid AND post_type IN($post_types) AND post_status = 'publish'");
} else {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_posts WHERE post_author = $uid AND post_type = '$type' AND post_status = 'publish'");
}
return mysql_result($result,0);
```

Many thanks!

Comment: I don't see any error messages?! Warnings are not the same as errors... Also, I don't see any mysqli in the code you provided..

Comment: Do not mix `mysql_*` and  mysqli_*`

Answer (score 0):

Naruto - Ah yes, you're right. They are Warning messages and not Errors, thanks for pointing it out - I'll update my initial post. What's the best way for me to address these Warnings as they are currently openly being displayed for users to see on the front end which gives the impression that the site is 'broken'.

Thanks for the feedback Jens. Care to elaborate a bit? I'm very new to this, am trying to 'repair' code that I just inherited and need as much hand holding as possible. "Do not mix mysql_* and mysqli_*` " ... Do I have them mixed up in the code I shared?